# Does a “refused Schengen visa” application affect future Employment/Jobseeker visa applications?

Tags: germany, schengen

My wife and I have been thinking to move to Germany through employment for quite some time. However, we decided to visit Germany first as a tourist, in order to get a better feeling about the country and the culture there. This would assure us that we are taking the right decision to move there permanently in future.

So, we recently applied for Schengen tourist visa through the German embassy in Malaysia. It took them 3 weeks to process our application and the outcome was refusal of visa due to the following reasons:

- Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided.
- You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence ...

I accept that I did not have enough funds in my bank account to assure them about my financial stability (I could have added more funds to my account if they had contacted me asking for that though).

Anyway! I decided to let go our decision for visiting Germany as a tourist and try to apply for Employment/Jobseeker visa this time. My concern is that our previous failed application for Schengen visa would affect our new application. Can anyone give me some advice regarding our situation? I really don't know what is the best action to take right now.

Answer (score 1):

I know many Malaysians in Germany and Czech Republic and even speak Malinglish =), but will avoid confusing other folk here and keep things straight.

You have broken no law and thus unlikely to have got a negative record.

Had you arrived here and they denied you entry, that would be more serious - but legally applying and they legally decline at most means you have a record showing your application.

I suggest you seek an employer who might sponsor you (DHL is an example as they have big facilities in Malaysia, Germany and Czech Republic).

Best of luck!

Comment: In addition both of the reasons for refusal are transient conditions. It's entirely conceivable that the OP could get even a future tourist application approved, though he should be careful not to engage in funds parking.

Comment: IT will though show on your record that you applied for a tourist visa first and on refusal you immediately applied for a work visa. It is not illegal but it raise suspicions about your intent.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark But most often the suspicion for short-stay visa applicant is that they actually intend to immigrate and work... which is legal on work visa.